# Handle schema change in Google datastore with Go?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

I added a new attribute to Go struct, persisted in a datastore entity kind.

I tried to load entities using a filter on the new attribute:

```
q := datastore.NewQuery("Person").Filter("Employed =", false)
```

This only worked as intended for persons created after the new attribute was added.

I had expected persons created before the attribute was added to be incleded in the filter, but they didnt have the attribute at all, so they were be excluded by the filter.

I have thought of two ways to handle this:

- First load all entities and filter in a second step with a loop. This adds complexity to the code.
- Batch load and resave all entities, which adds the property and sets it to false. I have to remember to do this every time I add a new attribute.

Is there a batter way to handle these types of entity schema changes?

Comment: I think you should be retrofitting your data rather than addressing this in application code. If you're updating the schema in a data store, you shouldn't add special features in your app to update things, you should fix the old data so what the app retrieves is consistent.

Comment: What is a good way to do that?

Comment: It depends on your datastore. In an SQL-compatible RDBMS you can specify a default value when adding the new column, e.g. `ALTER TABLE persons ADD COLUMN employed BOOLEAN DEFAULT true;`. Or in retrospect, you can `UPDATE persons SET employed = true WHERE employed IS NULL`. Of course, that simple `true` can be any expression depending on the existing columns' values.

Comment: The database is Google Datastore. Its a NoSQL database

Comment: @user1283776 how would run a query directly against the store? You can probably just use a normal update statement. I'm not familiar with the syntax for Google Datastore so I'd have to look into it a bit to give a more precise answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way is to re-save old entities if you can afford it.

You can use [Python map/reduce library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/dataprocessing/) to update old entities.

If you want to stick to Go you can go with simple batch processing using [task queues](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/taskqueue/) & [query cursors](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/query-cursors).

In our Python app we prefer "in-flight hot update" approach whenever it is possible - new version loads entities and check for missing properties. If some props are obsolete we would keep them for a month or to and then add logic to remove them. This allows to migrate gradually and often rollback without issues (shit happens) or at least limit impact to small % of records. Also it's more cost effective as you do not pay for additional reads/writes. Once we sure we ok we can run a mapreduce. This does not involve downtime. You may need or don't need downtime - it's really depend on your change.

With Go it may be a bit tricky as Go would panic if you try to load entity that has no corresponding fields on a struct. There should be some workarounds about it (*I remember something about special interface or a struct where you can load arbitrary entity*) but I have no much practical experience with Go on GAE yet.

Comment: What should our process be like? Say that we release our updated web app and then straight afterwards load and save all entities. Until the job is complete, users might encounter problems. Do we need top have downtime  and run this update job during the downtime to remove the risk of problems?

Comment: In our Python app we prefer "in-flight hot update" approach whenever it is possible - new version loads entities and check for missing properties. If some props are obsolete we would keep them for a month or to and then add logic to remove them. This allows to migrate gradually and often rollback without issues (shit happens) or at least limit impact to small % of records. Also it's more cost effective as you do not pay for additional reads/writes. Once we sure we ok we can run a mapreduce. This does not involve downtime. You may need or don't need downtime - it's really depend on your change.

Comment: See addition to my answer.