# How to use old schema(with no new columns) with a kind/table having new columns added, after a rollback

Tags: go, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-datastore

I have added some new columns in a kind in Google Cloud Datastore and new schema in Golang is reading that. Now if I want to rollback binaries to older schema because of some issue where these new columns do not exist, what is the ideal strategy for that? I have two options:

1. Write a script to delete new column from GDS when I want to rollback
2. Add a flag kind of feature to disable new columns so that the kind works with the older schema. I am not sure about this solution if is present.

Which is the ideal one and how to achieve them?

Comment: See if this old stackoverflow answer helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37578766/handle-schema-change-in-google-datastore-with-go

Comment: Could not find a concrete answer in golang. Can you help?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure a variable `omitempty` which can help in these situations. I found a good blog on it's explanation - https://www.sohamkamani.com/golang/omitempty/ .

If I store in DB a column with it's default zero value, then omitempty will not read it while reading json. In this way I will be able to use same golang schema with multiple DB schemas.

```
type User struct {
    ID           string        `json:"Id" datastore:"Id"`
}
```